# why do I get the keyerror exception?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, google-colaboratory, logistic-regression

here's the part of my code in googlecolab where I get the error :

```
   arguments = {'Epoch':6000, 'LearningRate':0.005}

   SoftmaxRegression = Multinomial_Regression(X_train,y_train,arguments)

   SoftmaxRegression.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

7 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 1
```

Can you help me please ?
PS : Multinomial_Regression reffers to a class that is built before
the code source : https://www.kaggle.com/code/vitorgamalemos/multinomial-logistic-regression-from-scratch

Comment: What does `Multinomial_Regression` refer to? Where is the doc for this function? Perhaps it requires some additional key/value pair in `arguments`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I edited it, thanks. I also put the source where I get my code, it's for building a logistic regression model.

Comment: is this FULL error message? It doesn't show which line in your code makes problem. Maybe problem is in different place.

Comment: the probleme reside only in the three last lines of code, cause in collab the first part runs correctly.

Comment: I found in the interne that the keyerror occurs when it comes to dealing with dictionnaries, which is my case ( first line of tha code I wrote in my question)

Comment: I rewrite the whole code on jupyter, the same error appears and it indicates that it resides in this line : SoftmaxRegression.fit(X,y)